# A href without actually getting forwarded to that page

Tags: arduino, href, forward

I'm currently working on an Arduino project. At this point I got web page which will tell the Arduino to turn on a light, or to turn off a light. In order to turn a light on or off, I have to enter a link. So far I've just simply done this with:

```
<a href="http://babla.com/turnlighton=1">Button tekst over here</a>
```

Check it live at: http://geertvandelangenberg.nl/innolab/

Now my problem is that once I hit one of these hyperlinks I will get forwarded to a page which will say that the request has succesfully been completed or not.

Is there any way to make a hyperlink which will just send the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator), without actually forwarding myself to that URL?

Comment: How do you want to "send an URL"?

Comment: Sorry for my English, i actually meant executing the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target your link to a hidden frame, add a frame to your page:

```
<iframe name='loader' style='display:none;'/>
```

And point your link to it by using the 'target' attribute:

```
<a href="http://babla.com/turnlighton=1" target='loader'>Button tekst over here</a>
```

If you care for the result of the `turnlighton` action, then go for an [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use an asynchronous [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) request ([AKA](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/AKA) [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)).

For example, you could use [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery), with the `.ajax` method: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.